# Using a .JS file as a reference library in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript

I want to put all my functions in js file and refer to them from my code in the extension is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wana use it from a html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/my_functions.js"></script>
```

If you wanna refer to them from a content script:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "path/my_functions.js"}, function(){
   oneOfMyFunctions();
});
```

If you wanna refer to them from the manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["path/my_functions.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

More info [available here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).